# If $\lim_{x\to+\infty}[f(x+1)-f(x)]= \ell,$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}x=\ell$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Let $f:[0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R$ be a function bounded on each finite interval.

I want to show that if $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}[f(x+1)-f(x)]= L,$ then also $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}x = L$

Comment: I've tried to make the title more informative and more searchable, but I feel there's still room for improvement.

Comment: thanks, the title is very important.

Comment: You want to "try that"? Isn't a "to show" missing in there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}[f(x+1)-f(x)]= L$, for any $\epsilon$ we have some $y>0$ such that 
$$x> y\implies |f(x+1)-f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
so for any $x>y$ we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)}{x} &=\frac{f(x)-f\left(x-\lfloor x-y\rfloor\right)}{x}+\frac{f\left(x-\lfloor x-y\rfloor\right)}{x}\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\lfloor x-y\rfloor}(f(x-i+1)-f\left(x-i\right))+f\left(x-\lfloor x-y\rfloor\right)\right)\\
&\leq\frac{1}{x}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\lfloor x-y\rfloor}(L+\epsilon)+\sup\limits_{z\in [0,y+1)}|f(z)|\right)\\
&\leq\frac{\lfloor x-y\rfloor}{x}(L+\epsilon)+\frac{1}{x}\sup\limits_{z\in [0,y+1)}|f(z)|\\
&\leq L+\epsilon+\frac{1}{x}\sup\limits_{z\in [0,y+1)}|f(z)|\\
\end{align}$$
which as $x\to+\infty$ approaches $L+\epsilon$. Letting $\epsilon\to 0$ gives the us $\limsup\limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}\leq L$. A similar technique shows that $\liminf\limits_{x\to+\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}\geq L$, finishing the proof.