# Check proof please

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Prove that if:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{f(x+1)-f(x)}=L$

than:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}}=L$

Assuming $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{f(x+1)-f(x)}=L$ we can choose $X_{\epsilon}$ s.t. $x>X_{\epsilon}$ implies $|f(x+1)-f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ Which means that for $x>X_{\epsilon}$:

$f(X_{\epsilon})+(x-X_{\epsilon})(L-\epsilon) < f(x) < f(X_{\epsilon})+(x-X_{\epsilon})(L+\epsilon) \iff$

$\frac{f(X_{\epsilon})}{x}+(1-\frac{X_{\epsilon}}{x})(L-\epsilon) < \frac{f(x)}{x} < \frac{f(X_{\epsilon})}{x}+(1-\frac{X_{\epsilon}}{x})(L+\epsilon) \iff$

$\frac{f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L-\epsilon)}{x}-\epsilon < \frac{f(x)}{x} -L< \frac{f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L+\epsilon)}{x}+\epsilon$

Now if we want $|\frac{f(x)}{x}-L|<\alpha$ for $x>X_{\alpha}$ we start by choosing an $\epsilon<\alpha$ and a corresponding $X_{\epsilon}$ s.t. $x>X_{\epsilon}$ implies

$\frac{f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L-\epsilon)}{x}-\epsilon < \frac{f(x)}{x}-L < \frac{f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L+\epsilon)}{x}+\epsilon$

Now we are going to make sure that for $x>X_{\alpha}$

$-\alpha<\frac{f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L-\epsilon)}{x}-\epsilon < \frac{f(x)}{x} -L< \frac{f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L+\epsilon)}{x}+\epsilon<\alpha$

First $-\alpha<\frac{f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L-\epsilon)}{x}-\epsilon$:

If $f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L-\epsilon)\ge0$: $x\ge0$

If $f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L-\epsilon)<0$: $x\ge\frac{X_{\epsilon}(L-\epsilon)-f(X_{\epsilon})}{\alpha-\epsilon}$

Now $\frac{f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L+\epsilon)}{x}+\epsilon<\alpha$

If $f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L+\epsilon)<0$: $x\ge0$

If $f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L+\epsilon)\ge0$: $x\ge\frac{f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L+\epsilon)}{\alpha+\epsilon}$

So now if we choose $X_{\alpha}=max(X_{\epsilon},\frac{X_{\epsilon}(L-\epsilon)-f(X_{\epsilon})}{\alpha-\epsilon},\frac{f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L+\epsilon)}{\alpha-\epsilon})$ Than we know that for $x>X_{\alpha}$:

$-\alpha<\frac{f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L-\epsilon)}{x}-\epsilon < \frac{f(x)}{x} -L< \frac{f(X_{\epsilon})-X_{\epsilon}(L+\epsilon)}{x}+\epsilon<\alpha$

And so that $|\frac{f(x)}{x}-L|<\alpha$.

Since we can do this for any $\alpha>0$: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}}=L$

Now this proof, if even correct, is definitely not very simple/elegant and I feel like this could be done easier. So please if you have a simpler proof share it, and if you see mistakes in this proof point them out. Thanks

Comment: [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192963/functions-with-eventually-constant-first-difference) another proof.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)?.

Comment: No I did not know that, but I'm also not supposed to use that. Just basic limit definitions.

Comment: I did not know about this Theorem - it is very useful.