# Prove that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = L$ if $\lim_{x \to +\infty} [f(x+1) - f(x)] = L \space$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f:[0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a bounded function in each bounded interval. If $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} [f(x+1) - f(x)] = L$$ then $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = L$$

I tried using the definition on the first limit; then, I attempted to use that inequality to apply the triangular inequality to arrive at the definition that gives me the second limit. It is supposed to be simple, but I'm not feeling safe as in how I should write it.

Comment: define $g(x)=f(x)-Lx$. Then you need to show that $g(x+1)-g(x)\to 0$ implies $g(x)/x\to 0$.

Comment: You just need to apply Stolz-Cesaro: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem

Comment: @A.S : Can you show how Stolz–Cesàro theorem can be used here?

Comment: @John What is there to show? Just apply it directly to all $f(\alpha+n)$ sequences (indexed by $\alpha\in[0,1)$).

Comment: Um... Is $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(\alpha +n)}{\alpha + n} = L$ for all $\alpha \in [0,1)$ sufficient to imply that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = L$? @A.S. (In particular, how is the boundedness of $f$ comes into play?)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192963/if-lim-x-to-inftyfx1-fx-ell-then-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the condition, for all $\epsilon >0$, there is $N=N_\epsilon$ so that

$$ |f(x+1) - f(x) -L|< \epsilon$$

for all $x\ge N$. Then for each $M = 1, 2, 3, \dots$, by induction on $M$ we have

$$ | f(x+ M) - f(x) -ML|< M\epsilon$$

if $x\ge N$. As $f$ is bounded on bounded intervals, there is $K >0$ so that $|f(x) | \le K$ when $x\in [N, N+1]$. So for all $x\in [N, N+1]$, $M\in \mathbb N$ we have

$$ |f(x+M)-ML| < M\epsilon +K.$$

Now for all $y\ge N$, there is $M$ so that $y=x+M$ for some $x\in [N, N+1]$. So for all $y\ge N$,

$$\begin{split}
|f(y) - yL| &= |f( x+M) - ML + ML -yL| \\
&\le |f(x+M) - ML| + |(M-y)L| \\
&< M\epsilon +K +(N+1)|L| \\
&\le (y -N)\epsilon + K +(N+1)|L| \\
&= y\epsilon +C,
\end{split}$$

where $C = -N\epsilon + K +(N+1)|L|$ is independent of $y$. So

$$ \left|\frac{f(y)}{y}  -L\right| \le \epsilon + \frac{C}{y}.$$

Now choose $N_1 \ge N$ so that $\frac{C}{y} <\epsilon$ whenever $y\ge N_1$. So

$$\left|\frac{f(y)}{y}  -L\right| \le 2\epsilon$$

whenever $y\ge N_1$. Thus

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = L.$$

Answer (score 2):

For each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N > 0$, such that for $x > N$, we have 
$$ |f(x + 1) - f(x) - L | < \epsilon$$.
Expand it, we have
$$ L -\epsilon + f(x) < f(x + 1) < f(x) + L + \epsilon$$
Use above relation, for each $y > N+ 1$, we have for some  $  N \le z \le N + 1 $,
$$  f(z) - z (L - \epsilon) < f(y) < f(z) +(y - z) (L + \epsilon) $$
Rewrite the abouve as
$$  f(z) + (- z) (L - \epsilon) < f(y) - yL < f(z) - z (L + \epsilon) $$
Furthermore
$$ |f(y) - Ly| \le \max_{N\le z\le N+1}|f(z)| + (N+1)(L+\epsilon)$$
Now,
let $M > N + 1 >0$ so that $\frac{max_{N<Z<N+1}|f(z)| + (N+1)(L+ \epsilon)}{M} \le \epsilon$

for $x > M$, $$|\frac{f(x)}{x} - L |= |\frac{f(x) - Lx}{x}|$$
$$ \le \frac {\max_{N\le z\le N+1}|f(z)| + (N+1)(L+\epsilon)}{M}$$
$$\le \epsilon$$

QED

Answer (score 0):

### Intuitive approach when $l \in \mathbb{R}$:

let $a:= x- \lfloor x\rfloor$ , $n :=\lfloor x\rfloor $

$$f(x)=f(a+n) = f(a)+ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} f(a+k+1)- f(a+k)$$

$$\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{f(a)+ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} f(a+k+1)- f(a+k)}{x}$$

Since $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x+1)- f(x) =l $ choose $N \in \mathbb {N}$ st for all $x>N$, $|f(x+1)- f(x)-l |< \epsilon$

$$= \frac{f(a)+ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} f(a+k+1)- f(a+k) }{x}+\frac{ \sum\limits_{k=N}^{n-1} f(a+k+1)- f(a+k) }{x}  $$
Note that the first fraction goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$ , the second fraction $\frac{n-1-N}{x}(l  -\varepsilon )< \frac{ \sum\limits_{k=N}^{n-1} f(a+k+1)- f(a+k) }{x}   < \frac{n-1-N}{x}(l  +\varepsilon )$ as $x \to \infty$ the this goes to $l$

---

### Rigorous proof:

Given $0<\varepsilon<1$ since $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x+1)- f(x) =l $ then  $\exists N \in \mathbb {N}$ s.t for all $x>N$, $|f(x+1)- f(x)-l |< \frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|}$.

Since $f$ is bounded on $[0, N+1]$ then let $k = N(1+3 \sup {|f(x)|})$ where $ 0\le x\le N+1 $. Now choose $M$ such $\frac{k}{M} \le \frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|}$

let $a:= x- \lfloor x\rfloor$ , $n :=\lfloor x\rfloor $

$$f(x)=f(a+n) = f(a)+ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} f(a+k+1)- f(a+k)$$

for all  $x >M$

$$\frac{f(x)}{x}= \frac{f(a)+ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} f(a+k+1)- f(a+k) }{x}+\frac{ \sum\limits_{k=N}^{n-1} f(a+k+1)- f(a+k) }{x}  $$

$$-\frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|}+ \frac{n-1-N}{x}(l  -\frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|} )< \frac{f(x)}{x} <\frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|} +\frac{n-1-N}{x}(l  +\frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|}3)$$

$$-\frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|}+ \left (1- \frac{a+N}{x}\right )(l  -\frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|} )< \frac{f(x)}{x} <\frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|} +\left (1- \frac{a+N}{x}\right )(l  +\frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|} )$$

$$l -3\frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|} -|l| \frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|}  < \frac{f(x)}{x} < l +3\frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|} +|l| \frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|} $$

$$-(3 +|l|)\frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|}  < \frac{f(x)}{x}-l < (3 +|l|)\frac{\varepsilon}{3+|l|}$$

$$-\varepsilon<\frac{f(x)}{x}-l <\varepsilon$$

$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}-l \right|<\varepsilon$$