# If $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{g(x+1)-g(x)}=l$ what are sufficient conditions to make $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, conjectures

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642662/prove-that-lim-x-to-infty-fracfxx-l-if-lim-x-to-infty-f) question it is proved in the answers that If $f :[0 , \infty ) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f $ is bounded on every $(a,b)$ such that $a<b <\infty$,  prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty }(f(x+1) - f(x) )=l$ implies $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty  }\frac{f(x)}{x}=l$.

This condition looks suspiciously similar to  Stolz-Cesaro theorem see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4858423/can-stolz-cesaro-theorem-be-applied-to-this-problem-if-lim-limits-x-to-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a proof of using  Stolz-Cesaro theorem .

---

My question is :  If If $f,g :[0 , \infty ) \to \mathbb{R}$  $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{g(x+1)-g(x)}=l$ what are sufficient conditions  for $f,g$ to make $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$?

Of course when $f$ and $g $ are both differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and if $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty } g(x)= \infty$ this condition   sufficient to make $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$, but this hypothesis is too strong is there a weaker hypothesis. and I want to generalise this result.

I conjectured this more general hypothesis  : If  $f$ is bounded on every $(a,b)$ such that $a<b <\infty$, $g$ is a continuous increasing function on $\mathbb{R}$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$.

I couldn't prove this result but I think it is true.

My question  is this conjecture true ? If it was true is there a weaker hypothesis ? If it wasn't true, Is there a weaker  hypothesis than $f$ and $g $ are both differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and ]$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty } g(x)= \infty$?

Comment: @Masacroso Sould $f$ be bounded ? and how to prove the limit exist ? could $g$ be only  monotone  ?

Comment: From ur hypothesis it seems $|f(x+1) -lg(x+1)|-|f(x)-lg(x)| <\epsilon$ if $|g(x)|\leq B$ for $x\geq N$ . It need not be the case $f(x)-lg(x) \rightarrow 0$

Comment: @Balajisb I $g$ diverges  in my hypothesis.